# Find all the solutions for $e^z=e^{iz}$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

so iam trying to solve this

$e^z=e^{iz}  $

so, since z = x+iy

$ e^{x+iy}  = e^{-y+ix}  $

so should i take the Log for the two sides ? or what should i do  ?!!

I really want the help!

Thanks

Comment: where z is in the form x+iy , where x,y belong to R (real values).

Comment: this is work if z ∈ $Real$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$e^{z(1-i)}=1=e^{2m\pi i}$$ where $m$ is any integer

Comment: amazing , so that's is the all solution in order to $e^z=e^{iz} $

Comment: so i should continue as follow (x+iy)(1-i)=2m$pi$i ??

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $$|e^z|=|e^{iz}|$$therefore $$e^x=e^{-y}$$which leads to $$x=-y$$therefore $$e^z=e^{iz}=e^{x+ix}=e^{x-ix}$$which reduce to $$e^{ix}=e^{-ix}$$hence the solutions are$$x=-y=k\pi$$and $$z=k\pi (1-i)\quad,\quad k\in \Bbb Z$$

Comment: that's why I am confused lol !!

Comment: Why then? If two complex numbers are equal, so are their absolute values while the angles do not need to be so.

Comment: yes you are right , but what is the solutions ? right !

Comment: that's better sir , thanks

Comment: You're welcome!!

Answer (score 0):

If $z,w\in\mathbb C$, then $e^z=e^w$ if and only if there is an integer $k$ such that $z=w+2k\pi i$. So, when do we have $z-iz=2k\pi i$ for some integer $k$?

Comment: z,w∈R numbers !!

Comment: Why should I suppose that $z,w\in\mathbb R$?

Comment: The question we are trying to solve giving me this hint !!!

Comment: The question that you are trying to solve has no $w$.

Comment: i got it sir , thanks alot